# Why can't regex find letters inside words?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm unclear as to why

```
re.compile("h").match("ohs")
```

Returns None, but it works if I remove the "o".

Comment: `re.compile("h").search("ohs")`

Comment: match only starts matching  from the beginning whereas  search searches in the entire string